# converting static local arrays to pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to remove static local variables from an already existing code. The idea is to move the static variable to a global structure. I am having trouble in changing multi dimensional arrays in that case.
for eg:

```
static int arr[100];
```

this I will replace with

```
int *arr = global_hndl->arr;
```

so that the following portion of code doesn't have to be changed.
is there any way to do the same for multi dimensional arrays?
like

`static int32_t delay[6][170]`

example

```
int foo(int x, int y)
{
    static int arr1[10];
    static int arr2[10][20];
    /*
    do something
    */
}

typedef struct _hndl
{
    int arr1[10]
    int arr2[10][20]
}global_handle

int foo(int x, int y)
{
    int *arr1 = global_handle.arr1;
    //
    /* i am trying to change arr2 in similar fashion */
}
```

Comment: Please pick a single programming language.

Comment: First, decide on a language, then provide a [mcve].

Comment: Note that, as you show the example, `global_hndl->arr` has no storage allocated.

Comment: Neither C or C++ have multidimensional arrays. `delays` is an array of other arrays.

Comment: @VTT, C has: `int a[10][10]; int *b[10];` can both be indexed as multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @VTT, `delays` is a block of memory of 6*170 `int32_t`'s.

Comment: ...and that's what is usually called multidimensional array, @VTT. What's the reason for you to reject that name?

Comment: Your change breaks any code that did `sizeof arr`

Comment: I am using C++, I added C just in case I can find a generic solution.

Comment: It's fairly easy to see that `arr[10][10]` must be multi-dimensional. `sizeof(arr) > sizeof(arr[0]) > sizeof(arr[0][0])`.

Comment: BTW, not my vote, but this seems a particularly dumb idea.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `delays` is a block of memory of 6 `in32_t[170]`, not a block of 6*170 `int32_t`. It is sure possible to write code that emulates multidimensional arrays though.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Because arrays have only a single dimension? Declaring something like `int a[10][10];` doesn't make it a single block of ints. And indexing of arrays always involves a sequence of operations on a single dimension ptr+offset. It is not possible to iterate in different dimensions (something like diagonal walk `p +={1, 1}` would involve two iterators `px +=1; py = px + y_offset;` ); It is sure possible to write code that emulates multidimensional arrays though.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn a variable definition into a type definition:

```
// variable
int arr[100];
// type
typedef int arr_type[100];
```

This works with any object. Now, you can replace any of them with the correct pointer type:

```
// somewhere global
arr_type global_array;
// create local reference
arr_type& arr = global_array;
```

This works in C++ only. In C, you'll have to use pointers which then require a different access syntax. That's exactly the reason why putting both the C and C++ tags into a question is usually wrong.

Comment: I am not in favour of having array as part of a typedef (it obfuscates the array).

Comment: I'm also not in favour of creating globals either, I guess we'll agree on that, @PaulOgilvie. However, in refactoring code, using references is the only way that really just moves these statics. And, it's still much more readable than defining and initializing an array reference without the typedef. OTOH, now that I'm thinking about it, could the new `auto` be used to avoid this step?

Comment: It might be better to just use std::array or std::vector, then pass data() to legacy code expecting raw pointers.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt "The new auto" is even worse practice than global variables and typedef arrays... so why not use all 3 at once.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you consider C++11 (?) `auto` bad practice, @Lundin?

Comment: Pointers are not always a replacement for arrays, @MaxVollmer, consider e.g. the `sizeof` operator. Using modern types (`vector<>`, `array<>`) is of course preferable in the long run, provided it's C++ at all, but when refactoring, it's sometimes easier to take small steps. Also, the OP is still confused about the programming language.

Comment: what does `arr_type& arr ` mean in c++?

Comment: It's a reference. Sorry, but that question and `typedef struct ..` show that you have a lot to learn about C++, you haven't covered the basics even.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Because it picks a type automatically, without care? `auto small_u8_array = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03};` or `auto result = DONT_USE_FLOAT ? 1 : 1.0;`. It is probably the most brain-dead programming language feature created this millennia.

Comment: So you advocate people don't use templates without fully specifying their parameters either, @Lundin? Sorry, I find that statement of yours with all the absolute claims in it ridiculous.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I advocate: don't use C++ - it will blow your leg off. While it is perfectly possible to use C++ in a safe and effective way, people never do that. They run off to write page after page of meta programming, using as many exotic language features as possible. If it ain't broken, it ain't got enough meta programming yet.

Comment: "people never do that" -- just because you don't, it doesn't mean I don't. Anyhow, I think we will not come to an agreement other than that we disagree in our views of reality.

Comment: @Lundin _"I advocate: don't use C++"_ That's seriously not helpful. Your comments are distracting and derailing, leading into a debate about opinions about language preferences. Just stop.